# How would you go about copying records from one web app to another when files are involved?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Suppose I have 2 web applications: App1 and App2. I have employee records in App1 that each contains references to their own picture. Those pictures are stored in the server where App1 resides.

Now in App2, I am supposed to have a migrate page that will copy all the employee records from App1 to App2. The records in the DB is straightforward to copy. But how do you go about copying each of the employees picture from App1 server to App2 server? I need to have a copy of the files in App2's server. The records can range from 500 to 2000 with each record having a picture.

I am copying the records by calling a REST POST API call to App1, but I am not sure how to include the files on that POST call or if I even should include it or should it be a separate call.

Answer (score 0):

1. One solution would be to make a separate API call for each file to be copied. This would require making one API call for each employee record, but would ensure that all the files are copied over. In addition, this solution would allow you to track the progress of the file copy process.
2. Another solution would be to include the files in the initial API call to App1. This would reduce the number of API calls needed, but would require some extra work to ensure that all the files are included in the call.